# "Cast to Number failed for value 1,1 at path"

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to build a user model with some privileges.

Schema looks like this:

```js
var mongoose = require("mongoose"), 
    passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");

let userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username:
    {type: String,
    unique: true
    },
    password: String,
    privileges:
    [{
            region: { type: Number, unique: true },
            read: Number,
            write: Number,
            edit: Number
    }]
});

userSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
```

POST route looks like this.

```js
router.post('/register', function(req, res)
{
    console.log(req.body);
    User.register(new User({
        username: req.body.username,
        privileges:{
            region: req.body.privileges['region'],
            read: req.body.privileges['read'],
            write: req.body.privileges['write'],
            edit: req.body.privileges['edit']
        }
    }), req.body.password, function(err)
    {
        if(err)
        {
            console.log(err);
            res.redirect("/register");
        }
        else
        {
            console.log("fine");
            passport.authenticate('local', {
                successRedirect: '/',
                failureRedirect: '/login'
            })
        }
    })
});
```

```html
<form action="/register" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="username"><br/>
    <input type="password" name="password"><br/>
    <input type="text" name="privileges[region]"><br/>
    <input type="text" name="privileges[read]"><br/>
    <input type="text" name="privileges[write]"><br/>
    <input type="text" name="privileges[edit]"><br/>
    <input type="text" name="privileges[delete]"><br/>
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Basically, it should work like this:
From the form I should get an array of privileges.
Now when I enter data in the fields like this:
test
1234 
1 2
1 1
1 1
1 1
(test - username, 1234 - password, 1 2 region array, 1 1 - read array, 1 1 write array, 1 1 edit array) I get this error:
[image: click]

Now I get the reason - privileges[edit] is type="text" and it can't be parsed into the DB as a Number. But why does it happen ONLY for edit? I find it strange.

I tried changing input type to number, but after that I can't enter an array anymore.

I think I might need a middleware which transforms the text into numbers. Am I right? If so, how should it do it? Should it transform each element of the array individually or the array as a whole?

Thanks.

Comment: _"But why does it happen ONLY for edit?"_ I bet that it happens for the rest of the fields. I like to think maybe the fields are validated against lexicographically. _"I tried changing input type to number, but after that I can't enter an array anymore."_ In the schema, priviledges is defined to be an array of fields; I don't get that in the markup; it is an object, ergo `privileges[region]`

Comment: I'm pretty new to this. How should I access it through the markup then if privileges[region] is not right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the schema defined for `User`, `privileges` is an array of SubDocuments having this schema.

```
{
    region: { type: Number, unique: true },
    read: Number,
    write: Number,
    edit: Number
}
```

When setting this field, the data provided needs to match that schema. *e.g.*

```
new User({
  username: req.body.username,
  privileges: [
    {
      region: ":region_value",
      read: ":read_value",
      write: ":write_value",
      edit: ":edit_value"
    },
    {
      region: ":region_value",
      read: ":read_value",
      write: ":write_value",
      edit: ":edit_value"
    },
    //....
  ],
})
```

I assume that the design for privileges was done purposely in this way to allow for a user to have many privileges.

A straightforward way to set privileges is to design the form appropriately. The form field can allow for setting several privileges. For example, to set two privileges, you can achieve that by writing the markup this way:

```
<input type="text" name="privileges[0][region]"><br/>
<input type="text" name="privileges[0][read]"><br/>
<input type="text" name="privileges[0][write]"><br/>
<input type="text" name="privileges[0][edit]"><br/>
<input type="text" name="privileges[0][delete]"><br/>

<input type="text" name="privileges[1][region]"><br/>
<input type="text" name="privileges[1][read]"><br/>
<input type="text" name="privileges[1][write]"><br/>
<input type="text" name="privileges[1][edit]"><br/>
<input type="text" name="privileges[1][delete]"><br/>
```

This way privileges in the `req.body` will have the right format e.g.

```
{ privileges:
  [ { region: '1', read: '2', write: '2', edit: '2', delete: '4' },
    { region: '2', read: '4', write: '4', edit: '4', delete: '4' } ] }
```

So that you can simply write

```
new User({
  username: req.body.username, 
  privileges: req.body.privileges
})
```

It's more straightforward to ensure the client passes the right data than trying to massage the data after the fact.

A limit in the design of the form this way means that the number of privileges that a user can have has to be determined ahead of time. A work around this is to build the form dynamically and give control to the user to add more privileges as the case may be. See the following example to get an idea about how to go about it:

```js
function addPrivilege(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const privileges =  $('.privileges');
  const lastCount = privileges.length;
  console.log($(this).data('template').replace(/:x:/g, lastCount))
  const template = $(this).data('template').replace(':x:', lastCount);
  
  privileges.after($('<div class="privileges"></div>').append(template))
}


$(document).ready(function () {

  $("#addPrivilegeBtn").on('click', addPrivilege);
});
```

```css
.privileges {
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  margin: 4px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div class="privileges">
    <input type="text" name="privileges[0][region]"><br/>
    <input type="text" name="privileges[0][read]"><br/>
    <input type="text" name="privileges[0][write]"><br/>
    <input type="text" name="privileges[0][edit]"><br/>
    <input type="text" name="privileges[0][delete]"><br/>
  </div>

  <button 
    id="addPrivilegeBtn"
    data-template='<input type="text"name="privileges[:x:][region]"><br/>
    <input type="text" name="privileges[:x:][read]"><br/>
    <input type="text" name="privileges[:x:][write]"><br/>
    <input type="text" name="privileges[:x:][edit]"><br/>
    <input type="text" name="privileges[:x:][delete]"><br/>'
  >Add privilege</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I tested it and it's working. I don't really get this though: "privileges[0][region]" in the markup. Shouldn't it be privileges[0].region (because [0] is the array and .region is the object's property, basically?). Thanks for your answer though, it's working, I just don't get that.

Comment: I think the format is `name[field][field]` where when field is an integer it is treated to be an array item. If `field` is alphanumeric, it's treated as a key in an object. When the same value for name is set for another form input, the value entered for those inputs are collected in an array. There is a rather dated spec about [submitting JSON data using HTML forms](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-json-forms/).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time!